# Module parse failed with custom npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm new to React and new to npm module publishing, there is a beginning for all things!

I have created a react module.

I have created a react app (using `create-react-app`) and i have imported the module directly (not via a `npm install`).
On this case, i got no errors. The app is compiling without problems.

However, when i'm trying to use my module by importing it from npm (after it's get published), it fails.

To get this issue, i have created another react app (always by using `create-react-app`) then i have installed my package using `npm i --save my-module-name`.

I'm importing it commonly by using `import { SomeComponent } from 'my-module-name'` instead of importing it directly.

And i got the following error

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (59:37)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     }
|
|     generateRecoverActionsContainers = () => {
|
```

After some searchs, it seems to come from the Webpack configuration. But, during my searchs, i saw that people recommand to not touch the react Webpack default configuration.

From there, i'm a bit lost on how to fix that and also, why it was compiling when the module was imported directly and not compiling when it was importing from node_modules... Should i had a webpack configuration in my npm module?

Thanks in advance for your precious help!

Answer (score 0):

When you publish a module on npm, you should publish compiled code. Webpack doesn't compile `node_modules`

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. I don't see how i can build this type of module (which is a react component). Do you have any tutorial in mind that can guide me to do this the right way ?

Comment: Use babel. Take this tutorial for instance: https://medium.com/@tmtushar28/getting-started-with-webpack-aae37062c01